# How to make Spinner editable?

Tags: android, android-widget, spinner

I changed the ArrayAdapter method of spinner and i got my custom Spinner.
just change the parameter of this method like

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>   adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(This,R.array.statename,R.layout.mylayout);
 spinner.setAdapter(adp);
```

In Which the mylayout file contains

```
<EditText 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
 android:textColor="#FF8B1500"
 android:gravity="center"
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use auto completionText I think this can fix your problem .